# multiple string replace from json data

Tags: php, json

here is the code I have written

```
<?php 
            $response = file_get_contents('like.json');
            $arr =json_decode($response);
            foreach($arr->likes->data as $category){
                $findme    = $category->name;
                $search = 'Lets play Cricket today, what do you say about playing Bangladesh cricket CHI?';
                $pos2 = stripos($search, $findme);
                if ($pos2 !== false) {
                    $search = str_ireplace ( $findme , '<b>'.$findme.'</b>' , $search );
                    echo $search;               
                }       
        }

?>
```

here, I am getting array of string in $category->name like 
 Bangladesh, Cricket, CHI, Sport ....
Now in my $search string I have a small paragraph for instance, I want to replace any word that matches from the $category->name array. but problem is if it gets multiple replaces then it printing out that many times.

I dont know how to solve it, should be easy but cannot get it right.

Comment: Did you see regular expressions (regex) ?

Comment: regular expression as in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare and output variable `$search`outside the loop.:

```
$response = file_get_contents('like.json');
            $arr =json_decode($response);
$search = 'Lets play Cricket today, what do you say about playing Bangladesh cricket CHI?';

foreach($arr->likes->data as $category){
   $findme    = $category->name;
   $pos2 = stripos($search, $findme);
   if ($pos2 !== false) {
      $search = str_ireplace ( $findme , '<b>'.$findme.'</b>' , $search );            
   }       
}

echo $search;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all category names in search string first replace them then echo the search string this way:

```
$response = file_get_contents('like.json');
$arr =json_decode($response);
$search = "Lets play Cricket today, what do"
         ." you say about playing Bangladesh cricket CHI?";
foreach($arr->likes->data as $category){
    $findme    = $category->name;
    $pos2 = stripos($search, $findme);
    if ($pos2 !== false) {
        $search = str_ireplace ( $findme , '<b>'.$findme.'</b>' , $search );
    }
}     
echo $search;
```